# FtpWebRequest 530 Not Logged In only with EnableSsl

Tags: c++-cli, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to bolt some C++/CLI FtpWebRequest code on top of a legacy C++ application (VS2008). The first snippet of code below works fine WITHOUT EnableSsl, but as soon as I add EnableSsl I get 530 Not Logged In. So, the EXACT same code, credentials, URI, etc, just with or without the EnableSsl line.

All the other answers I could find ended up being server configuration or credential problems, but Filezilla client works fine with explicit FTPS, and the second snippet of code below (C# in VS2015) works fine with EnableSsl, and the first snippet works fine without EnableSsl.

How can I get FtpWebRequest working with EnableSsl in my VS2008 C++/CLI application?

**EDIT:** In VS2008, the C# code also has the same "works without EnableSsl / 530 with EnableSsl behavior" as the C++/CLI code. So, C# vs C++/CLI is no longer a data point, but I'm still hoping someone knows how to get EnableSsl working in VS2008.

```
// First snippet, C++/CLI VS2008, works fine WITHOUT EnableSsl line, 530 WITH EnableSsl line

FtpWebRequest^ ftpRequest = dynamic_cast<FtpWebRequest^>(WebRequest::Create(gcnew Uri(_T("ftp://server/path/dst_file.ext"))));
ftpRequest->Credentials = gcnew NetworkCredential(_T("username"),_T("password"));

ftpRequest->Method = WebRequestMethods::Ftp::UploadFile;
ftpRequest->UseBinary = true;
ftpRequest->EnableSsl = true;

StreamReader^ srcStream = gcnew StreamReader(_T("src_file.ext"));
array<Byte>^ fileData = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(srcStream->ReadToEnd());
srcStream->Close();
ftpRequest->ContentLength = fileData->Length;

Stream^ reqStream = ftpRequest->GetRequestStream();
reqStream->Write(fileData,0,fileData->Length);
reqStream->Close();

FtpWebResponse^ ftpResponse = dynamic_cast<FtpWebResponse^>(ftpRequest->GetResponse());
ftpResponse->Close();


// Second snippet, C# VS2015, works fine WITH EnableSsl

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://server/path/dst_file.ext");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.EnableSsl = true;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(new StreamReader("src_file.ext").ReadToEnd());
writer.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Comment: What happens if you eliminate the differences between your two tests? Use the same version of Visual Studio, compile both C# and C++/CLI as either 32 or 64 bit (doesn't matter which, but make them the same). I'd also make the actual upload code exactly the same. (And I probably wouldn't use StreamReader or StreamWriter: Those classes want to use Strings & formatted data, use raw Stream objects to work with your file & the upload as raw bytes instead.)

Comment: When I compile them both in VS2008, the C# code has the same behavior as the C++/CLI code did. Updated my post.

Comment: Try ftpes://server/etc...  https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTP_over_TLS

Comment: This is how I was connecting with FileZilla, but it doesn't work with FtpWebRequest - I just get "the uri prefix is not recognized".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is that VS2008 doesn't support .NET versions with recent cryptographic protocols, and there isn't any practical way to work around it without upgrading (https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/).